# PGF's `foreach` recognises when there are no list items and doesn't run the code. Is this guaranteed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, loops, pgffor

The PGF `\foreach` macro behaves differently when the item list is totally empty than it does when a single item happens to be empty.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {,} {Hello}

\foreach \x in {} {How are you}

\end{document}
```

Gives this result:

```
HelloHello
```

This behaviour is quite convenient if you are programming macros that take comma-separated strings as user input. It means that you do not have to add logic to check whether there are truly any list items. However, it does not seem to be mentioned in the PGF manual. Is it guaranteed not to change in future versions of PGF/TikZ?

Comment: You should probably ask that question to the authors/maintainers themselves.

Comment: It would be _much_ more efficient if you did your own test first before passing arguments to `\foreach` (which does a _lot_ before getting to the list itself).

Comment: Can you show some typical uses of `\foreach` in your code? If you don't use the `...` feature of `\foreach`, there are more efficient loops that also avoid the quirk of locality.

Comment: @egreg, I was thinking of putting the code I am working on up on the Code Review Stack Exchange, maybe that is what I should do when it is more complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it is more efficient to avoid `\foreach` and do your own tests for empty lists or list items. Also anything done within a `\foreach` iteration has to be done globally to last past the end of the loop.

There may be packages which already provide this functionality but here is an example of what could be done. It contains a bit more than is strictly necessary simply to provide more informative output:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
% \@ifnextchar is provided by LaTeX
\def\mycommand{\@ifnextchar[{\mycommand@}{\mycommand@[]}}
\def\mycommand@[#1]{%
  \def\my@strings{#1}%
  % \@empty already provided
  \ifx\my@strings\@empty%
    \my@nostrings% <- Don't really need this.
    \let\my@next=\relax%
  \else%
    \let\my@next=\my@parsestrings%
  \fi%
  \my@next%
}

\def\my@parsestrings{%
  \my@beforestrings% <- Don't really need this.
  \expandafter\my@@parsestrings\my@strings,\my@parsestop,%
}

\def\my@parsestop{\my@parsestop}

\def\my@@parsestrings{\@ifnextchar x{\my@@@parsestrings}{\my@@@parsestrings}}

\def\my@@@parsestrings#1,{%
  \def\my@string{#1}%
  \ifx\my@string\my@parsestop%
    \let\my@next=\my@@@@parsestrings%
  \else%
    \let\my@next=\my@@parsestrings%
    \ifx\my@string\@empty%
    \else%
      % Process string
      \my@processstring{#1}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \my@next%
}

\def\my@@@@parsestrings{%
  \my@afterstrings% <- Possibly don't need this.
}


\def\my@nostrings{%
  {\tt No strings}%
}

\def\my@beforestrings{%
  {\tt Processing strings}%
}

\def\my@afterstrings{%
  {\tt\\ Finished strings}%
}

\def\my@processstring#1{%
  {\tt\\\hskip0.25in[string:`#1']}% 
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{2in}
\mycommand

\color{red}
\mycommand[]

\color{green!50!black}
\mycommand[a,b,c]

\color{blue}
\mycommand[a,,b,c,,]

\color{purple}
\mycommand[   a,  ,  b,  c, ,]
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reading between the lines, I think the core thing that you're telling me is that for LaTeX programming it is best not to use PGF's \foreach because it's slow. (I do appreciate you providing the example code though.)

Comment: I think that you will measure no difference between `\foreach` and a different list implementation unless you are operating *heavily* with lists... and `\foreach` is both flexible and powerful. Why not using it until one finds a performance bottleneck?

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, I will probably do as you suggest since I have already written a fair amount of code that uses `\foreach`.